# Updating and delete data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting syntax error as,

> unexpected '{' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sherukh\resources\views\student\index.blade.php)

I don't know where my syntax error i check all the way i did not find any error
and my delete query is also not working is there any location error because when i press the delete button it takes me to wrong page

```
 @foreach($students as $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$row['first_name']}}</td>

                <td>{{$row['last_name']}}</td>
                <td><a href=" url('student/edit/'.$row['id'])"class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                <td>
               <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{ action('StudentController@destroy/'.{{$row['id']}} )}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
     </form> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: put your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is in your form action : 
change it as,

```
 <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{ url('student/'.$row['id']) }}">
```

You already used {{ }} so no need to use again if you want to use any variable.

Comment: Action App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@destroy/1 not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sherukh\resources\views\student\index.blade.php) i am facing this error now

Comment: public function destroy($id)
    {
        $student = Student::find($id);
        $student->delete();
        return redirect()->route('student.index')->with('success', 'Data Deleted');
    }

Comment: this fuction is in my controller class

Comment: Show me your route file

Comment: Route::resource('student','studentcontroller');

Comment: Edited answer. change action to route

Comment: i use post method is any other way you can guide to make things easier

Comment: If you use resource route, it will use delete method, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Remove "open and end inner curly braces {{" from the action attribute.Replace below code with your code.

```
@foreach($students as $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$row['first_name']}}</td>

                <td>{{$row['last_name']}}</td>
                <td><a href=" url('student/edit/'.$row['id'])"class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                <td>
               <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{ action('StudentController@destroy/'. $row['id'] )}}">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
     </form> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//blade
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.tag.update',$tag->id) }}">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="form-group form-float">
    <div class="form-line">
        <input value="{{ old('name') }}{{ $tag->name }}" name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
        <label class="form-label">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<a href="{{ route('admin.tag.index') }}"  class="btn btn-danger m-t-15 waves-effect">{{ __('BACK') }}</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">{{ __('SUBMIT') }}</button>
</form>
//controller
  public function edit($id)
    {
        $tag = Tag::find($id);
        return view('admin.tag.edit',compact('tag'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $tag = Tag::find($id);
        $tag->name = $request->name;
        $tag->slug = str_slug($request->name);
        $tag->save();
        Toastr::success('Tag Successfully Updated','Success');
        return redirect()->route('admin.tag.index');
    }
```